# How can I simulate decltype in a trailing-return-type before C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98

If I have for instance this in C++11:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto add(T1 t1, T2 t2) -> decltype(t1 + t2)
{
    decltype(t1 + t2) val = t1 + t2;
    return val;
}

int main()
{
    double a = 12.5;
    int b = 4;
    std::cout << add(a, b) << std::endl; // prints 16.5
}
```

I can return a type that can be determined automatically by the compiler.

As I'm new to C++ and currently need to implement something like this in C++98, does anyone know how I would go about that?

Comment: That *does not* determine at *runtime* what type will be returned, but at *compile-time*.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: There were other error in the exposition-only code.

Comment: What does "something like" mean? This mechanism was not added to the standard for typing convenience, it was impossible to do to such extent before. You had to have a well defined return type with out any evaluation. You could only pass another type or try some SFINAE magic for guessing some predefined combinations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Commonly, in C++98/C++03, to keep things simple we did this manually:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename R, typename T1, typename T2>
R add(T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
    R val = t1 + t2;
    return val;
}

int main()
{
    double a = 12.5;
    int b = 4;
    std::cout << add<double>(a, b) << std::endl;
    //              ^^^^^^^^
}
```

([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/909670f691e489ee))

That this sucks a lot is precisely why `decltype` and *trailing-return-types* were added to the language.

Comment: One *could* automate that with type-traits, but that also sucks big-time, as one needs to define lots of templates and specializations for it to work.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yeah. Looked into it very briefly but decided it was not worthwhile for this answer (nor for someone's code!), and detracted from the main point somewhat: the point being that there is a reason C++11 added stuff like this ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I didn't know `decltype` was referred to as a "trailing-return-type"

Comment: @ZWiki: It's not, but in your example you're using it inside one. `auto functionName(argument_list) -> trailing-return-type { definition }`